# Cut the first and the last part of a string in bash

Tags: bash, cut

I have a string having this formats:

```
aa_bb_cc_dd
aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff
```

I want to obtain:

```
bb_cc
bb_cc_dd_ee
```

I've tried 'cut', but I didn't manage to obtain what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using `bash` you can use built-ins for this task:

```
strip_headtail() {
 local s=$1
 ## strip the head
 s=${s#*_}
 ## strip the tail
 s=${s%_*}

 echo ${s}
}

strip_headtail aa_bb_cc_dd
strip_headtail aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff
```

you might want to check the bash-manual (`man bash`) for more information on this. 
search for *Remove matching prefix pattern* resp. *Remove matching suffix pattern*.

Comment: I consider pasting large documentation parts as spam.  A reference should be enough.

Comment: @Alfe thanks for the hint. it's always a question what "large" means...in any case i replaced it with something more terse...

Comment: It makes sense to quote such pieces if you want to comment on a specific detail of the quoted text, but if it is just a _see also_ kind of thing, I prefer the way you chose now :-)

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ echo "aa_bb_cc_dd
aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff" | awk -F_ '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1); NF=NF-2}1' OFS=_
bb_cc
bb_cc_dd_ee
```

#### Explanation

- `-F_` and `OFS=_` set input and output field separator as `_`.
- `{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1); NF=NF-2}` set each field as the next one, so the nth will be the (n+1)th. Then, decrease number of fields in 2.

---

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ echo "aa_bb_cc_dd
aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff" | sed -e 's/^[^_]*_//' -e 's/_[^_]*$//'
bb_cc
bb_cc_dd_ee
```

#### Explanation

- `sed -e` is used to do multiple commands.
- `'s/^[^_]*_//'` delete from the beginning up to first `_`.
- `'s/_[^_]*$//'` delete from last `_` up to the end of line.